# Остановить функцию python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть такой код, где функция get_value делает запрос к определённому ресурсу и возвращает ответ этого ресурса:

```
data = get_value()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция прерывалась, если она выполняется более 1 секунды? Иначе весь скрипт может подвисать секунд на 30 (асинхронность и потоки не вариант, потому что скрипту нужно узнать, что запрос не удался сразу, а не через 30 секунд)

*Не особо важная информация:
Пишу сайт, который позволяет управлять температурой в устройствах.
Все устройства и сервер находятся в одной локальной сети. Некоторые устройства могут отваливаться и не отвечать. Для связи с устройствами используется протокол Modbus TCP и библиотека pyModbusTCP. Когда устройство не отвечает, то эта библиотека в течение секунд 30 пытается подключиться к нему и сервер не может вернуть ответ клиенту в течение этого времени. Я не могу изменить механизмы работы этой библиотеки. Вопрос: как можно прервать функцию, если она выполняется более 1 секунды?*

Comment: первое что сказал google  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887184/pymodbus-tcpclient-timeout

Comment: _"потоки не вариант, потому что скрипту нужно узнать, что запрос не удался сразу, а не через 30 секунд"_, — не понимаю Вашего следствия. На поток можно поставить `timeout`. Кстати, `timeout` можно поставить и на любой запрос к внешнему ресурсу.

Comment: @splash58 спасибо большое, просто я документацию читаю по диагонали, мой косяк